# pandas get distributions of values within group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe like:

```
  cens codf  codid
0  S01  F01      1
1  S01  F01      2
2  S01  F02      3
3  S01  F03      4
4  S02  F04      5
5  S02  F05      6
```

I am trying to select a random sample from each `cens` group according to the distribution of `codf` counts within each group. Basically if I groupby:

```
In [387]: df.groupby('cens')['codf'].value_counts()                                                                                                               
Out[387]: 
cens  codf
S01   F01     2
      F02     1
      F03     1
S02   F04     1
      F05     1
Name: codf, dtype: int64
```

In the S01 `cens` group that the `codf` should have a (non-normalized) probability distribution like a vector:

```
[0,33 0,66 0,66]
```

which means that 1 time a have a `codf` with value 2 and two times two `codf` with value 1. I would like to get a sample of let's say 50% of the rows from each group according to the previous distribution.

I know that I can:

```
df.groupby('cens').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5))
```

but the problem here is adding the previous vector to the `weight` keyword in the `sample` function. I tried to add it to the original dataframe but so far I can only add a colum with the relative occurrences. The dataframe with the column distribution (non-normalized) should appear as:

```
  cens codf  codid pdf
0  S01  F01      1 0.33
1  S01  F01      2 0.33
2  S01  F02      3 0.66
3  S01  F03      4 0.66
4  S02  F04      5 1.00
5  S02  F05      6 1.00
```

and then I should be able to write:

```
df.groupby('cens').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5, weight=df['pdf']))
```

Comment: What would a possible output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using `value_count` , Since you want to assign the value back to original df , I am using `transform`

```
s=df.groupby(['cens','codf']).codf.transform('count')
s1=df['codf'].groupby([df['cens'],s]).transform('nunique')
s1
Out[256]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: codf, dtype: int64
df['pdf']=s1/df.groupby(['cens']).codf.transform('nunique')
df
Out[258]: 
  cens codf  codid       pdf
0  S01  F01      1  0.333333
1  S01  F01      2  0.333333
2  S01  F02      3  0.666667
3  S01  F03      4  0.666667
4  S02  F04      5  1.000000
5  S02  F05      6  1.000000
```